# Running time of locating a file in a directory

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, file-management, algorithm

When you search for a file in a directory with a large number of files (`n`), what is the worst case running time of locating this file? I mean does the OS (linux) sequentially check all filenames in the directory to find a match (`O(n)`) or does it support a kind of more intelligent dictionary indexing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a start of an answer.   Each file has an inode object associated with it.  The inode is filesystem-specific, which is why you cannot normally have hard links that span across filesystems.   The kernel maintains an inode cache which may be updated whenever the OS has to open/reference a file not in the cache. The inode number is accessed after the first visit via an "index" or a hash.

So a simple `ls` command could read all directory entries to get a file - linear time - or it could use the inode cache. I believe McKusick's BSD ffs implementation was the first to use caching like this.

Newer filesystems are much better with gigantic directories, however once the number of items becomes really large, like millions, `ls` response times may go down the tubes. Because of cache size limits. Or because the file is not cached.  ufs (newer version of ffs) does this.  ext4 (Linux )is much better, IMO.  Most OSes maintain statistics on lookup efficiencies - try your version of iostat.  This is part of filesystem tuning, i.e., sizing the inode cache.

So bottomline, no one answer fits everywhere.  And there is usually caching.  But it is maintained LRU because most kernels have an inode cache size limit, so an inode that gets used once a month may be moved out of the cache.